# MPI Strategy - parallelization into a function - MPI_Gather

Tags: c++, c, arrays, parallel-processing, mpi

I try to parallelize a code with MPI. In this code, the part to parallelize is located in a function. I have to convert a sequential loop into MPI parallel loop.

After this MPI loop, I have to get a global array and I intend to use MPI_Gather to have this array.

Here's the structure of the code :

```
int main() {

    double *array_global;

    data1 = read(file1);
    data2 = read(file2);

    data3 = compute_on_data(data1, data2);

    write(file3,data3);

    function_to_parallelize(data1, data2, data3, array_global);

}
```

and the function "`function_to_parallelize`" :

```
function_to_parallelize(data1, data2, data3, array_global) {

  int i;

  for (i = 0;i<size_loop; i++)
     {
       compute(data1, data2, data3, i, array_global);
     }

   write(file4, array_global);

}
```

My first question is : Can I do a MPI parallelization by doing in the main (adding `rank_mpi` and `nb_process` arguments):

```
int main() {

int rank_mpi, nb_process;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); 
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank_mpi); 
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nb_process);

    double *array_global;

    data1 = read(file1);
    data2 = read(file2);

    data3 = compute_on_data(data1, data2);

    if (rank_mpi = 0) {
      write(file3,data3);}

    function_to_parallelize(data1, data2, data3, *array_global, rank_mpi, nb_process);

}
```

and do in "`function_parallelize`"

```
function_to_parallelize(data1, data2, data3, array_global, rank_mpi, nb_process) {

  int i;

  double *gathered_array_global;

  int size_block = size_loop/nb_process;

  for (i = rank_mpi*size_block; i < (rank_mpi+1)*size_block; i++)
     {
       compute(data1, data2, data3, i, array_global);
     }

   MPI_Gather(gathered_array_global, array_global, 0); // Gather all array_global into gathered_array_global for root process "rank_mpi = 0"

   if (rank_mpi = 0) {
     write(file4, gathered_array_global);}
}
```

?? I mean, if I use MPI_Gather into the function, can I have the desired result, i.e all the `array_global` are put into the final array that I want to write in "`file4`" ?

I only know that, traditionally, MPI_Gather is used into main() for collecting all the subarrays. If I am into a routine, I think that processes can't synchronize itself wwith others processes and hence can't communicate between them, is it right ?

My second question is about the strategy to adopt for this parallelization : do you think that all processes can read "`file1`", "`file2`" without having conflicts between them ?

For writing "`data3`", I think that I can only write for only one process (`rank_mpi = 0`), otherwise, there will be errors at the execution

Thanks for your help and advices

Comment: If the only reason you want to do the MPI_Gather of array_global is to write it out, you probably want to look at MPI-IO instead.  That will likely also help with writing data3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo-code would run if written in the proper syntax.  There isn't any problem with using MPI calls in functions other than main.  BUT I don't think it would do what you want.  Using MPI calls in your `function_to_parallelize` is fine, but lets take a closer look,

```
function_to_parallelize(data1, data2, data3, array_global, rank_mpi, nb_process) {
  int i;
  double *gathered_array_global;
  int size_block = size_loop/nb_process;
  for (i = rank_mpi*size_block; i < (rank_mpi+1)*size_block; i++)
     {
       compute(data1, data2, data3, i, array_global);
     }
   MPI_Gather(gathered_array_global, array_global, 0); // Gather all array_global into gathered_array_global for root process "rank_mpi = 0"
   if (rank_mpi = 0) {
     write(file4, gathered_array_global);}
}
```

You break the problem up such that only part of each `array_global` on each process will have been computed.  For example, suppose you have `rank_mpi` is `0-3` and `size_loop=40` so that `size_block=10`.  That means that `array_global[0-9]` will be calculated on process 0, `array_global[10-19]` on process 1 and so on.  Then when you call `MPI_Gather` you will need a `gathered_array_global` to be of size `nb_process * size_loop` to hold the data.

I think what you want is to make smaller local array that just fit the data that is calculated (in other words array of size 10) and then pass them to MPI_Gather to be collected into an array of size 40 (gathered_array_global).  Of course you will also have to be careful in case the size of the array is not exactly divisible by the number of processes you are using.

Having all processes read from files at the same time in theory is OK, but you can easily break almost any file system by asking for large numbers of simultaneous reads.  I would use a broadcast, but it depends on your exact situation.

Lastly, unless using a parallel output library, you can't have more than one process write to a file at the same time. No matter what file system you're using this has the potential to break things.  Best to do what you were thinking and gather then write from one process.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, now I know I can use MPI_Gather in a function and this will work for gather all my arrays. I thought that, given we are into a function, it was not possible (actually, without having real arguments). For I/O, this is what I saw on different MPI forums : Reading for all processes is OK, but I have to be careful with writting.